# CentOS df misreports free disk space (due to mounted volume?)

Tags: centos, hard-drive, disk-space-utilization, df

I have a server with an LVM volume mounted under /mnt. When running `df -h` to check free disk space, it appears to show the space consumed under /mnt as being used in /:

```
[root@monitor spool]# df -h
Filesystem                            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root                50G   44G  6.2G  88% /
devtmpfs                              2.4G     0  2.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                 2.4G  128K  2.4G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                 2.4G  197M  2.2G   9% /run
tmpfs                                 2.4G     0  2.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-home                85G   33M   85G   1% /home
/dev/sda1                             497M  204M  294M  41% /boot
/dev/mapper/recordings-newrecordings  394G   42G  332G  12% /mnt/newrecordings
/dev/mapper/data-db1                   50G  364M   49G   1% /mnt/db
```

Whilst this does have a certain logic - after all /mnt *is* under / - it does incorrectly indicate that the space is being used under / when in fact its on a separate mounted volume. This is causing some problems as our SNMP monitor keeps misreporting the / volume as nearly full, when it isn't.

Edit: Further to comments below, to illustrate my point better

`ncdu` shows the available disk space as follows:

```
ncdu 1.11 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help
--- / --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   42.3 GiB [##########] /mnt
    1.4 GiB [          ] /usr
  917.9 MiB [          ] /var
  234.5 MiB [          ] /run
  178.0 MiB [          ] /boot
   21.9 MiB [          ] /etc
   19.1 MiB [          ] /root
  188.0 KiB [          ] /home
  132.0 KiB [          ] /dev
    4.0 KiB [          ] /tmp
.   0.0   B [          ] /proc
    0.0   B [          ] /sys
@   0.0   B [          ]  lib64
@   0.0   B [          ]  sbin
@   0.0   B [          ]  lib
@   0.0   B [          ]  bin
e   0.0   B [          ] /srv
e   0.0   B [          ] /opt
e   0.0   B [          ] /media
    0.0   B [          ]  .autorelabel
```

Comment: What's your basis for this belief?

Comment: / is 50GB but only contains approx 2GB of data - yet df reports the disk as having 44GB used.

Comment: / is your root filesystem and not /root which is roots home - you root partition is 88% full

Comment: That doesn't sound right - /root only contains 20MB and it's 50G in size!  `du -sh /root     20M /root`

Comment: /mnt doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: @michael so where is the space going on /?

Comment: It's going to whatever is on your filesystem! Have you tried actually looking?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes of course I have - have edited the question to illustrate. As far as I can see, the only thing using any significant space is `/mnt`. What am I missing?

Comment: Unmount them and try `ncdu` again.

Comment: Will have to wait until off-hours, can't do that in the day :-/

Comment: to clarify the reason for doing the check after umount: if there's any data in the directory /mnt/db or /mnt/newrecordings, this will be hidden by the mounted filesystem. But it would still take up space.

Comment: There is 42GB of data in /mnt/newrecordings so that would make sense?